# Origin of "you have nothing to fear if you have nothing to hide"?

Tags: etymology, phrases

What is the origin of the phrase

> You have nothing to fear if you have nothing to hide.

I see it occasionally bounced around, sometimes as an authoritarian slogan. Brief research indicates some think it was coined by Goebbels, some by Orwell.

Is the true origin known?

Comment: What makes you thing this has a particular "origin"? It is a fairly generic statement that has doubtless been independently uttered countless times throughout history, and not only in English.

Comment: It is an appallingly false platitude.

Comment: @HotLicks Could be Mark Twain. He reveled in such plain-spoken idiocies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> **You have nothing to fear if you have nothing to hide.**

The phrase - widely used in discussions of Internet security and uttered by Pius Thicknesse in *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* - is most commonly attributed to Joseph Goebbels in 1933.

However, there is an earlier precedent. Upton Sinclair used an inverted version in 1918 in *The Profits of Religion: An Essay in Economic Interpretation*:

> Not merely was my own mail opened, but the mail of all my relatives and friends—people residing in places as far apart as California and Florida. I recall the bland smile of a government official to whom I complained about this matter: ‘**If you have nothing to hide you have nothing to fear**.’

Comment: Good find. I suppose 'an earlier precedent' can make sense, though I wouldnlt use it here.

Comment: The inverted version has a different meaning.